# Alternative to motion blur for deformed objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, motion-blur

The documentation for Cycles in Blender 2.79 is [very explicit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/motion_blur.html) about deformation motion blurs:

> An object modifier setup that changes mesh topology over time can not render deformation motion blur correctly. Deformation blur should be disabled for such objects.
>
> Common examples of this are animated Booleans, Deformation before Edge Split, Remesh, Skin or Decimate modifiers.

This text is no longer in the [Cycles documentation for 2.93](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html), nor is it in the [documentation for 3.5](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html), however it is still very much a problem, specifically in the case of a mesh with multiple vertex groups being translated via shape keys, while intersecting with a mesh set as a target for a Boolean modifier set to "Difference". I don't have a minimal reproducible example handy, but the result is flickering and texture distortion. Autosmooth is also off for this mesh, which is sometimes mentioned as the culprit in similar situations, and keeping Motion Blur enabled but Deformation disabled seems to disable motion blur entirely for the object.

Is there any way around this? Can I simply not have motion blur enabled for this object?